# Delete captcha option in a Contact Form

Tags: html, forms, contact-form-7

How can I delete the captcha option in form from [formsubmit.co](https://formsubmit.co/)? It says I should add this in my code (line 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">

      <!-- Modal for Contact - us Button -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contáctanos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Phone">Celular</label>
                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Celular" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Email">Correo</label>
                  <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="Email-1" placeholder="Correo" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Message">Mensaje</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje" required></textarea>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:0;display:block;width:100%">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that line of code within the `<form>` tags.

```
  <!-- Modal for Contact - us Button -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contáctanos</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"> <!-- ADD THE LINE HERE -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Phone">Celular</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Celular" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Email">Correo</label>
              <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="Email-1" placeholder="Correo" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Message">Mensaje</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje" required></textarea>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:0;display:block;width:100%">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).